# Assembly: converting to if statement using two fld, fcomp, fnstsw and test 41h

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, fpu, x87

Could some one please help me with understanding the following code?

```
fld qword ptr [L1000F168]
fcomp   qword ptr [L1000A2F0]
fld qword ptr [L1000F168]
fnstsw  ax
test    ah,41h
jnz L100012F0
```

It is output of a compiler converted to assembly from executive code.

What I have caught till now is that

```
if(value[L1000F168] != value[L1000A2F0])
   continue following
else
   goto L100012F0
```

Am I correct?

I do not understand why `[L1000F168]` is loaded two times and why `ah` is compared with `41h` here? as `41h` means (Invalid operation) or (stack fault)?

Comment: AH contains bits 8-15 of AX, so it has bits 8-15 of the status word. $41 corresponds to bit14=C3 and bit8=C0, as Peter Cordes says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm#sword) for info on the x87 status word.

Note that the 16bit status word is stored to `ax`, but the `test` instruction is only looking at the upper 8 bits (`ah`).  So `41h` matches the `C0` and `C3` bits of the status word.  Using an 8-bit test on `ah` avoids a slowdown on Intel CPUs from using 16-bit `test` with an `imm16`.  (operand-size prefix changes the length of the rest of the instruction, the so called length-changing prefix decoder stall).

`fld / fcomp / fld / fnstsw`:  That looks weird to me, too.  I wondered if the goal was to have things like the denormal bit in the status word set based on the memory location, but `C0` and so on set based on the `fcomp`.  (This isn't what you get, because `fld` leaves the `C0-3` undefined or set.)

Intel's insn reference manual says `fld` leaves `C0` and `C3` undefined, so the compiler that generated this code was depending on some specific behaviour.  Maybe without an `fwait`, the status word wouldn't be updated from the `fcomp` yet?  I haven't grokked the whole `fwait` thing.  I haven't found (or looked hard for) an explanation of when you needed `fwait` on old CPUs, and when you didn't.  As I understand it, you never do on P5 or later.

Anyway, I *think* what this code does is:

```
if (! ([L1000F168] > [L1000A2F0]))
    goto L100012F0;
```

Testing not-greater is the same as testing `<=` or unordered.  This assumes that `fld` doesn't actually modify `C0` and `C3`.  Maybe the manual only says it leaves them undefined because it can set them when loading a denormal, or some other condition?  Or maybe it doesn't at all in current silicon.  Or maybe it's yet another error in the Intel manual, and this is actually known to be fine.  Or maybe this code doesn't work anymore!  Better test it with a debugger.

I think a more sensible way to get to the result the programmer was probably hoping for would be

```
fld    qword ptr [L1000F168]
fcom   qword ptr [L1000A2F0]
fnstsw ax
test   ah,41h     ; C0|C3: both zero iff st(0) > [L1000A2F0]
jnz    L100012F0
```

Since the OP says the code was compiler output, I guess that means it didn't have good x87 optimizations to avoid pop/reload of the same value.

[For P6 and later CPUs](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm#fcomi):

```
fld    qword ptr [L1000F168]
fcomi  qword ptr [L1000A2F0]
jna    L100012F0   ;  jump unless st(0) > [L1000A2F0]
```

I possibly have the sense of one of the comparisons backwards, so double check this if something doesn't make sense.

What's this code from?  Is it compiler output?  Or might it have been hand-written asm?

Comment: This looks like the output of a disassembler.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is a part of code of an executable file generated by a compiler. So as you say, it is a `if(value[L1000F168]>value[L1000A2F0])`? Did I understood correctly? Does it depend on something else that is previously loaded into stack?

Comment: btw, before this code, the stack has no extra pushed value more than what has come from the start of function.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: yeah, I figured out it was reverse engineering a binary, but the binary could have been created by assembling hand-written asm.  I guess the compiler wasn't smart enough to use `fcom` and save a load.  (and that back then, `fld` didn't leave `C0` and `C3` undefined.  Or maybe without an `fwait`, storing the flags at that point did get the flags from the compare?)

Comment: @barej: I updated my answer to answer your comments.  It doesn't depend on a previous `st(0)`, it just depends on x86 undefined behaviour of `fld` not touching some bits in the status word.

Answer (score 0):

fcomp   qword ptr [L1000A2F0] compares stack[0] with the value inside L1000A2F0 and pops it at the end of the stack.

```
example
stack[0] = 50
[L1000A2F0] = 45

if (stack[0] > [L1000A2F0])
pop stack[0]; // (stack[7] = stack[0])
else
pop [L1000A2F0]; // (stack[7] = [L1000A2F0])
```

hope this helps.